EXCEL: Count all unique values in Table column up to a certain point, and combine them into a single string?
I'm working on a D&D character sheet model in Excel (2021), which uses a Table to fill in the data per level. The current thing I'm running into is the Class and Level field, which tells you how many levels you have taken in each class, and what subclass each has (if any). It's a bit long to explain in text so here is a simplified version of the end result I am looking for:



Level
Class
Subclass
Tot_Class




1
Wizard

Wizard 1


2
Cleric
Arcana
Wizard 1, Arcana Cleric 1


3
Cleric
Arcana
Wizard 1, Arcana Cleric 2


4
Wizard
Illusion
Illusion Wizard 2, Arcana Cleric 2



Of course I could input these things manually, but I would prefer a formula to calculate the Tot_Class per row.
The formula I've gotten so far is:
=TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;(UNIQUE(FILTER([Class];([Level]<=[@Level])*([Level]>0)))))
This will result in "Wizard, Cleric" at Level 4, which obviously is only part of the equation. I'm thinking that functions such as the LET function will probably be helpful here, but I don't want to spend hours on something that just isn't going to work, so I would love some insight on how to set up this formula if possible.
TLDR: I need a formula that counts each unique value in the Class column up until that row's level, then create a string which gives (for each class): the last given subclass for that class + Class value + Count of class in column up to current level + ", " as delimiter.

For level 4 you show Illusion Wizard 2, Arcana Cleric 2 while literally the data shows Wizard 1, Illusion Wizard 1, Arcana Cleric 2 should subclass be ignored in the count for class? I think adding a little more examples would help.

Context: In this system, classes gain access to a subclass at different levels. They can only ever get a single subclass, which stays the same for every level afterwards. While Cleric gains a subclass at their first level, Wizards only gain a subclass at their second level. So when another level is put into wizard at level 4, it gains its subclass, meaning it needs to be added to the Tot_Class. You can choose different Classes to level up every time, all with their own subclass, the formula needs to keep that in mind. So, yes, you only count the Class, but add subclass to name if it has one.

The formula does:

Define unique Classes
Count the occurence of each
Detect the last subclass for each
Create concatenated text

The formula in cell I2
=LET(cl,UNIQUE($B$2:B2),
cntcl,COUNTIF($B$2:B2,cl),
last,XLOOKUP(cl,$B$2:B2,$C$2:C2,,0,-1),
TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,last&" "&cl&" "&cntcl))

In cell F2 if upgrade to 365 or TAKE is avail.
=LET(cl,UNIQUE(TAKE(Table1[Class],ROW()-1)),
cntcl,COUNTIF(TAKE(Table1[Class],ROW()-1),cl),
last,XLOOKUP(cl,TAKE(Table1[Class],ROW()-1),TAKE(Table1[Subclass],ROW()-1),,0,-1),
TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,last&" "&cl&" "&cntcl))

EDIT
On comment of the asker:
Removed unnecessary space from the end of the strings.


Thanks for the solution! The second option worked for me, although I did have to remove the last &" " at the end there, as it only seemed to add an extra space at the end for me (and before the comma).

Exactly. It is only a typo. I edited the post.

@LyranderNB I'm surprised you say the second option works for you. It involves TAKE which is not available in Excel 2021.

@P.b I think he/she means the second on the screenshot.

I think you're right

Interestingly, the Take function initially worked, but when I opened up the file today, it suddenly changed to _xlfn.TAKE and it stopped working. So very strange indeed. Currently looking at the I2 formula, but that doesn't quite work for me, as it refers to specific cells rather than the table column. To my understanding, referring to specific cells rather than named ranges like table columns is less flexible, especially when you start adding rows or moving columns, but maybe it's okay. Let me try it out.

The whole $B$2:B2 and then dragging it down to the rows below works for me as expected. I slightly altered last TEXTJOIN section to get rid of unnecessary spacing as follows: TEXTJOIN(", ";TRUE;IF(last="";"";last&" ")&cl&" "&cntcl)). This solution seems to be working for me (let's hope it remains functional this time).

Okay, I have confirmed my main worry about this solution (i.e. under current rules, no, you cannot have multiple subclasses for the same class), so I think it should work.  (Formula written for Level 3)
=LET(_class, B$2:B4, _subclass, C$2:C4,
    c_Unq, UNIQUE(_class),
    s_Unq, UNIQUE(FILTER(HSTACK(_class,_subclass), _subclass<>"", {"",""}), TRUE),
    _classLevels, MAP(c_Unq, LAMBDA(_c, TEXTJOIN(" ", TRUE, IFERROR(VLOOKUP(_c, s_Unq, 2, FALSE),""), _c) & " " & COUNTIF(_class, _c))),
    TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE, _classLevels)
)

This will create a Unique list of Classes (c_Unq), and a unique table of Class/Subclass pairs (s_Unq; ignores classes without subclasses).



_class
_subclass




Wizard



Cleric
Arcana


Cleric
Arcana






c_Unq




Wizard


Cleric






s_Unq[Class]
s_Unq[Subclass]




Cleric
Arcana



It will then run through the list of Unique Classes, prefix them with the Subclass if it exists, and append the count of how many times that Class appears to the end.



_classLevels




Wizard 1


Arcana Cleric 2



Finally, it will use TEXTJOIN to combine that list into a single value

Wizard 1, Arcana Cleric 2


Thank you for your contribution. This formula did not seem to work for me, as my excel was unable to recognize the MAP and LAMBDA functions, leading to a #NAME? error.

I think this would work in Excel 2021:
=LET(c,INDEX([Class],1):[@Class],s,INDEX([Subclass],1):[@Subclass],u,UNIQUE(c),TEXTJOIN(", ",,TRIM(u&" "&XLOOKUP(u,c,s,,,-1)&" "&COUNTIF(c,u))))
